# Reload previous visited page in javascript

Tags: javascript, onclick

I have a web page whithin i have display an image, when someone clicked on the image, The image is poped-in. And then, there is a close button after viewing the photo.

Now, I would like to add the the event onclick one function that allow me to refresh/reload the page. So I will have this sequence ( close popin ==> back to the page ==> reload the page)

Am not good in JS, i would like to do it in javascript.

Answer (score 0):

To reload the *current* page, you can use:

```
location.reload(true);
```

To reload the *previous* page, you can try:

```
history.go(-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you can do this, look [here](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/page/reload.html) for more info.

A call to `window.location.reload()` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to completely reload the page (i.e. resending any POST requests that may have occurred), use `location.reload()`.  If you do this on a POST request, the browser will ask you if you want to submit the data again (if you use this technique).

If you want to avoid resending a POST request but just GET the resource this time round, use `location.href = location.href`.